# Android start system service at app startup

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In the AndroidManifest.xml I register a BroadcastReceiver to the "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" event.
This starts the service each time the Android device boots.

```
...
        <receiver android:name="MySystemScheduleReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
...
```

However, I'd like the system service to be started right after app installation without the need to reboot the device.

Is there a system event that I could use when the app starts?
Or do I need to set a custom event?

Should I modify my manifest file to something like

```
...
        <receiver android:name="MySystemScheduleReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="com.myapp.StartSysService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
...
```

and then launch the service from my main activity with something like

```
...
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.myapp.StartSysService");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
...
```

If so, which method should I use? (onCreate, onResume...)

Thanks

Comment: "However, I'd like the system service to be started right after app installation without the need to reboot the device" -- system services are part of the firmware, not an app. Please edit your question to be **complete and accurate** about what you are referring to.

Comment: Do you have any GUI Activity? If yes, you can start the service on the **onCreate** method from your activity like this: `Intent service = new Intent(); service.setAction("com.myapp.MyService"); context.startService(service);`

Comment: I placed the sendBroadcast call in onCreate (main GUI activity) and it seems to work fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can subclass the Application, which has an onCreate() callback. You can start your service there.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
        // start your service
    }
}
```

In the `<application>` tag of your manifest, add `android:name="MyApplication"`